# Travel from the UK to Finland with a Spanish Schengen visa

Tags: uk, schengen, finland

I have a Spanish Schengen visa. I am now In Spain and I will go soon to the UK, and then I'm planning to go to Finland,

Does a multiple entry visa allow me to go from the UK to Finland rather than going to Finland through Spain?

I have been told that in order to be able to enter to Finland I have to go from  Spain directly to Finland. I'm just worried about the Finnish customs, they might say that I have to be in the Schengen territory in order to enter Finland with my Schengen visa.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but isn't Spain, UK and Finland part of Schengen?

Comment: UK is not part of the Schengen Agreement.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException UK isn't part of Schengen

Comment: Ok I see, then the German Wikipedia page about Schengen is useless ;) http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengener_Abkommen . There the picture indicates that UK is part of Schengen.

Comment: @RoflcoptrException How so? Schengen countries are either dark or light blue. UK and Ireland are green

Comment: Ok this is really a great coincidence but now there is another map there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, as long as you have a valid multiple entry Schengen visa, you can enter and exit the Schengen territory as many times as you want. Which in this case means you're allowed to fly from the UK to Finland. Of course, you need to have a separate visa for the UK if you need one.

Comment: I have a Uk visa as well,  
I entered Spain 1st with my spanish schengen visa so that's okay, But I'm still worried about things when I'm in the UK.
Are you sure that It's okay to go from the uk to finland?

Comment: Yes. A Schengen visa is valid for all countries that are part of the agreement, you don't necessarily need to be going from the country that issued it.

Answer (score 0):

Your Schengen visa is valid for all Schengen countries, if you have the multiple entry visa  you are allowed to enter/exit the Schengen area as you please for an accumulative period of a maximum of 90 days within a 180 day period.

and since you have a UK visa as well, you will have absolutely no problem at all with your Spain-UK-Finland routing.

[check out our site for more info](http://www.schengenvisahq.com) (affiliated with site)

Comment: If you're going to link to your own site, please indicate that it's yours.

Comment: sorry, I will do so in future entries, and will edit previous entries accordingly